# Php ssh detect end of stream

Tags: php, ssh, stream

I'm having troubles to detect the end of the stream from a ssh connection. This is what i tried:

```
<pre><?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("localhost", 22)))
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
else
    if(!$ssh = ssh2_auth_password($con, "viassh", "sshpass")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } 

        $sshStream = ssh2_shell($con, 'xterm', null, 80, 24, SSH2_TERM_UNIT_CHARS);
        $strCommand = 'cd /var/www/test';
        fwrite($sshStream, $strCommand . PHP_EOL);
        stream_set_blocking($sshStream, true);

        // infinite loop
        #$stderr_stream = fgets(ssh2_fetch_stream($sshStream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR), 8192);
        #var_dump($stderr_stream);

        // infinite loop
        #var_dump(stream_get_contents($sshStream));

        $ret = "";
        while ($buf = fgets($sshStream)) {
            $ret .= $buf;

            // always false
            #$meta = stream_get_meta_data($sshStream);
            #var_dump($meta['eof']);

            // works
            if(strpos($buf, '$ cd ') !== false) break;
        }
        $strCommand = 'git status';
        fwrite($sshStream, $strCommand . PHP_EOL);
        stream_set_blocking($sshStream, true);
        while ($buf = fgets($sshStream)) {
            $ret .= $buf;
            if (strpos($buf, '-a') !== false) break;
        }
        fclose($sshStream);
        echo $ret;


?>
```

that gives me the correct output:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

20 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Oct 23 16:45:20 2012 from localhost

cd /var/www/test
]0;viassh@rcdev: ~viassh@rcdev:~$ cd /var/www/test
git status
]0;viassh@rcdev: /var/www/testviassh@rcdev:/var/www/test$ git status
# On branch develop
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ssh_1.php
#   modified:   ssh_1.php~
#   modified:   ssh_shell.php
#   modified:   ssh_shell.php~
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ssh_stream1.php
#   ssh_stream1.php~
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

but only because i know the last line of the stream. I tried feof(), but that failed too.
So hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: Have you tried fread or stream_get_contents?

Comment: Its commented out in the script. I always get a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could do that just as easily with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)?:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('git status');
?>
```

Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do though?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is known behavior. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-shell.php

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this is an old question but I want to add my input because I couldn't find a working code snippet online. phpseclib is not always a suitable replacement - in particular, it lacks a reliable way to execute commands in sequence. I found the PHP extension to be more reliable and also easier to use.

My solution is below, which seems to work great in our setting. The principle is simple: the system is asked to print a BEGIN message before the output and an END message after the output (base64 is used for this but there are plenty of other ways). The function waits for the END before returning whatever was printed to the console in between the markers.

```
function executeCommand($connection, $command)
    {
        $shell = ssh2_shell($connection, 'xterm');
        sleep(1);
        stream_set_blocking($shell, true);
        printf("Running command: %s\n\n", $command);
        fwrite($shell, 'echo "LS0tLUJFR0lOLS0tLQo=" | base64 --decode;'.$command.';printf "\n";echo "LS0tLUVORC0tLS0K" | base64 --decode;'.PHP_EOL);

        $output = '';
        $output_start = false;
        while (true) {
            $buffer = fgets($shell);
            flush();
            if(strpos($buffer, "----BEGIN----") !== false) {
                $output_start = true;
                continue;
            }
            if(strpos($buffer, "----END----") !== false) {
                break;
            }

            if($output_start) {
                printf("%s\n", $buffer);
                $output .= $buffer."\n";
            }
        }
        print("Finished executing command\n");
        fclose($shell);
        print("Shell closed\n");
        return trim($output);
    }
```